# Not a valid jar when I was running an example of Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming, mrjob

I am learning Hadoop recently. I am using sandbox on virtualbox. I downloaded a python script with mrjob frame and run the following command,

```
python RatingsBreakdown.py -r hadoop --hadoop-streaming-jar /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-streaming-jar u.data
```

and then got this,

```
Running step 1 of 1...
Not a valid JAR: /usr/hdp/2.6.3.0-235/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming-jar
```

Comment: You didn't give an actual jar file. Typically those end in `.jar`, not `-jar`... Please verify the file path you gave actually exists

Answer (score 0):

```
lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar
```

This is the jar in my computer  ,
a valid jar is end with `.jar`  your command is has some mistakes .
you can   open the folder to observe (`cd foldername)` the filename   or  try to use  `tab` to completion your file name .In that way to reduce mistakes.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! You're right. I tried to find a file named **"hadoop-streaming*.jar"** in hadoop folder and I found one. I made an alias. But the following step still doesn't work. The command I use is **Python name.py u.data -r hadoop --hadoop-streaming-jar HADOOP-STREAM > result.out** where name.py is my mrjob and u.data is the data file. I got a lot STDERR. it shows: Creating temp directory -> Copying local files to hdfs -> STDERR Unable to load native-hadoop library -> and more. BTW it works on local but hadoop.

Comment: @Jacob That must be another question , had you use **-file  or   -files** arguments?  I dont know more about   Python !